# r unsplit to get original dataframe back

Tags: r

I have question about unsplit in R. Really appreciate if you could help.

I splitted a dataframe into smaller dataframes, by two factors.

```
mydf.list=split(df.original,list(factor1,factor2))
```

How do I use unsplit to get my dataframe back?  I tried following, but didn't work.

```
df.updated=unsplit(mydf.list,list(factor1,factor2))
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please share sample data

Comment: Works for me - `unsplit(split(mtcars, list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs) ), list(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. This example is based on the `mtcars` dataset, and @thelatemail's comment

```
data(mtcars) #load dataset
mydf.list<-split(mtcars,list("cyl","vs")) #split the dataset
unsplit(split(mydf.list, list("cyl", "vs") ), list("cyl", "vs")) #rejoin the dataset
```